# File share not showing up as service, although it says the configuration offered it

Tags: azure, azure-storage, fileshare, azure-storage-files

File share not showing up as service, although it says the configuration offered it.  Why isnt File Share available and only Blob container?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you're using the Premium (Hot Access) tier.  This is strictly for blob storage.

---

[image: Premium Blob Only Warning]

---

Though this premium constraint isn't mentioned, the types of storage account can be found here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-account-overview

If you need high performance file storage (no requirement for any other services), when creating the storage account select Premium for Performance and FileStorage for Account Type.

Comment: It would be nice if you can provide a link about storage types :)

Comment: I saw the FileStorage option alone, so if I select that Account kind then it will have only that option, which is fine.

Comment: That's right.  Make sure you need the premium performance tier as it's a lot more expensive than standard V2 which gives you all services.

Comment: My website pulls images and other types of files from this storage. It's a pretty high performance site, although we do use CDN.   I am trying to compare prices to see how much higher but having a hard time.

Comment: If it's of any use in my experience I've found that fronting your storage with a CDN almost nullifies the number of transactions served by the storage account, but this is in cases of having less than 100 artifacts stored in a cold tier blob storage account.  The images got there through a piece of middleware hence our ability to use blob instead of file, but I can see how this would add significant complexity to your typical static content.  If your images are changed infrequently, standard tier would suffice for most.  You could create 2 accounts with one image on each to get a feel.